# What is a Bank-Run Equilibrium (Diamond-Dybvig Model)?

Tags: banking

I have an assignment on Bank-Run Equilibrium, studying the Diamond-Dybvig Model. The question goes as:
Suppose the mass of depositors is equal to 10, θ = 1/2, and r = 1. Suppose that y1 = 1.2 which implies that y2 = 1.6.1 Also, suppose that 40% of all depositors are never paying attention and will definitely not go to the bank in period 1. So the only question is whether the 10% of all depositors who do pay attention and did not get a liquidity shock
will go to the bank. **Is there a bank-run equilibrium?**

I understand the basics of the Diamond-Dybvig model, my question is that, what is the definition as a "Bank-Run Equilibrium"? Is it a condition when the actual customer who will go to the bank is actually higher than θ (the probability of a segment of a customer will go to the bank and take their deposits)? Or what? And what should I do to prove whether there is or there is not a Bank-Run equilibrium?

Thank you!